# Google Apps Script Multiple users using same functions and javascript issues

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am looking for some advice on what to read up on. I am trying to make a webapp for my school that teachers can user for the school reward system. It is designed as a front end to a google sheets spreadsheet. The teachers log how many housepoints a child has earned in a lesson via a table with a column of text inputs (one for each child in the class) The webapp then adds these to the spreadsheet using the appendrow method.

I have one problem currently and need some advice on what I should do about another issue I can see on the horizon!

Current issue:
I have a javascript function that checks the housepoint values that have been added to each child collects a list of ids and the number of housepoints and sends these to google apps script as attributes of an object via a for loop.The apps script then strips the attributes and adds the data to a spreadsheet. The issue is as I understand it the apps script takes too long to append the rows and the javascript for loop does not wait for the apps script to catch up. The result is that it misses some of the data out and only appends a fraction of the rows it should do. Is there a way to get the javascript function to pause and wait for the app script to say its ready for the next object?

Potential issue: As this script is meant to be used by multiple teachers at the same time I am worried that if the same function (to add the housepoints to the spreadsheet) is called at the same time by different users what will the app script do? I would imagine it will collapse. I have tried to investigate what to do on this and have to say I do not understand what I am reading. What I really want is the app script to "park" each request in a cue and then chug through them at its own speed. Is this possible?

As you may have guessed I am not an experienced programmer, I am willing to read up and learn but just would like someone to point me in the right direction. Many thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Read documentation on Lock Service. [https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock-service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock-service)

Comment: I think you should share the Sheet (without sensitive data, a sample) and the code, to see if it can be optimized. Also, you should consider using a database instead, since Sheets it's not really meant to be used as one, since running Scripts on it, specially several people at the same time is not efficient.